# Email piping not working for PHP script. Local delivery failed error

Tags: php, email, pipe, piping

In cPanel I have piped the following to my script:

```
alerts@XXX.com  to  |/home/XXX/public_html/client/inc/msg/mailReader.php
```

I get the following email returned:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> pipe to |/home/XXX/public_html/client/inc/msg/mailReader.php
>       generated by alerts@XXX.com
>       local delivery failed

The path to mailReader.php is definitely correct, as well as the path to PHP in the shebang in mailReader.php.
Line 1 is:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/php -q<?php
```

Do you have any idea why it would return the "local delivery failed" error?

Comment: Here is the exim_mainlog entry: http://pastebin.com/CuFmrzBG

Comment: is the PHP script actually exectuable? (chmod +x on /home/XXX/public_html/client/inc/msg/mailReader.php)

Answer (score 1):

The directory was actually #!/usr/bin/php -q. I have 2 other directories that have the files for PHP but this isn't looking for the PHP directory, its looking for the compiled PHP file in bin called "php".